# how to protect a textbox from reading and writing using user32 dll?

Tags: dllimport, user32

sorry for any inaccuracy in the terms: I would like to avoid which the value of a textbox(.net windows forms) that it is readable-writable  by other applications through for example the functions of lib user32,how could this be done?,thanks, my best regards

Comment: That's not going to be possible. Once you have hostile software running on the same machine as your program, it's game over. Why are you letting this hostile software run on the sensitive machine?

Comment: I have do an application (using c #) that could run for tests on a machine not mine, I would like to prevent the password entered from a textbox from being stolen by software that performs a user32 function to copy the text of the password textbox

Comment: How is that software going to get to run on your machine?

Comment: I run it from visual studio, but maybe I didn't understand the question

Comment: No. I mean the malicious software that is stealing passwords. How does it get on the machine?

Comment: it is only a hypothesis

Comment: Generally, if arbitrary software has been installed then it could do all sorts to steal your data. Key logger for instance. And plenty more. You are probably just wasting time.